# Deserializing JSON using JSON.NET

Tags: .net, linq, json, .net-3.5, json.net

I already have the answer for this using silverlight's System.JSON but specs got changed and now I need to do it in .NET 3.5

here's the JSON I'm getting

```
{"SearchResults":[{"PageCount":"1"},
{"SEARCHVAL":"Result","CATEGORY":"Category1","X":"1","Y":"2"},
{"SEARCHVAL":"AnotherResult","CATEGORY":"Category1","X":"2","Y":"2"}]}
```

and the solution using System.JSON assembly was

```
var resultList = ((JsonArray)searchResults["SearchResults"])
   .OfType<JsonObject>()
   .Where(o => o.ContainsKey("SEARCHVAL"))
   .Select(o => new SearchResult() { 
       SearchValue = o["SEARCHVALUE"],
       Category = o["CATEGORY"].
       X = o["X"],
       Y = o["Y"]
   }).ToList();
```

I figure most of the code is similar/exactly the same but I'm not sure about the ContainsKey's counterpart in JSON.net. I think it's the Contains() method but I'm not exactly sure how to use it so that I could get the X and Y of the SEARCHVAL.

**UPDATE:**

so here's my code to get the JSON stream and parsing:

```
       ...
       Uri uri = new Uri(url);

       WebClient client = new WebClient();
       ParseJSON(client.OpenRead(uri)); 
    }


    private void ParseJSON(Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream == null)
            return;

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        JObject searchResult = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());

        string x= searchResult["SearchResults"][0]["SEARCHVAL"]["X"].ToString();
        string y= searchResult["SearchResults"][0]["SEARCHVAL"]["Y"].ToString();

        // use data
        ...
```

and I'm getting a null exception on `string lat = searchresult...`. Any clue where I went wrong on using JSON.NET?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's the working solution using JSON.NET:

Getting the json:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead(uri)))
        {
            json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Parsing the stream as JObject:

```
        JObject searchResult = JObject.Parse(json);

        string lat = searchResult["SearchResults"][1]["X"].ToString().Replace("\"","");
        string lon = searchResult["SearchResults"][1]["Y"].ToString().Replace("\"","");
```

the .Replace() can be disregarded if there are no unnecessary characters included on the parsed string. I was using Json.NET 3.5 so you'll probably won't need to do this in the most updated release.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JObject.Parse method in JSON.Net... http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializingJSONFragments.html

Then something like this would get the desired values:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(yourstringjson);
string name = (string)obj["SearchResults"][0]["SEARCHVAL"]["X"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing string manually using linq I would suggest you to use inbuilt [JsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class.

This [reference msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/01/30/asp-net-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx) suggests the use if it.

Also, IMO it would be great to use System.JSON when we do not have strongly-typed class. But in your case you have an class made for it so using in-built functions is more better and also personally I love to use anything that comes in-built.

(posting from mobile)

Comment: You linked to JavaScriptSerializer. Indeed it would be good to used System.JSON if it's not restricted to Silverlight.